# TCP connection with Python sockets - send() function issue

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to establish TCP connection on the client-side using socket. The first part seem to work fine:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 1234        # The port used by the server
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Now for the `send()` the server-side requires:

*Once a client is connected it needs to send the following string in order to send a marker*: `<TRIGGER>XXXX</TRIGGER>`In our case XXX is defined as `var.`trigger

When I write it like `s.send(bytes (var.trigger))` it runs with no errors, however, I guess because it is not defined as a string the server does not recognize it.

Thank you in advance
p.s. I don't code in Python so it can be something very basic that I am missing here.

Comment: Try `s.send(bytes(f"<TRIGGER>{var.trigger}</TRIGGER>"))` or use concatenation if you're running python 2. Also consider posting a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which includes the definition of `var.trigger`.

Comment: Wait, how does this return with no errors? Is `var.trigger` already a `bytes` object? Anyways, you'll need to decode `var.trigger` if it's `bytes` and encode the f-string in my example for it to work.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thank you so much. I will try to make it work this way. I actually don't know whether the TCP server is receiving bytes or strings, and var. triggers are values (e.g. 1, 2, 3). I will chack that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am also fairly new to python sockets, but I tried this and it worked. My guess is that you need to wait for the data to be sent (on your server side) with something like this:

```
    while True: # Infinite loop
        data = conn.recv(1024)  # 1024 = number of bytes to be recieves
        if not data:  # If data is false, or an empty string/list, etc.
            break
        print("Recieved:", data.decode('utf-8')) # Printing recieved data
```

The full code is as follows:

```
import socket

# ========== SERVER ==========

def server():
    s = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Setting up socket
    HOST = '127.0.0.1' # Localhost
    PORT = 65432

    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept() # Accepting connection
    print("========== SERVER ==========")
    print("Connected by:", addr)
    while True: # Infinite loop
        data = conn.recv(1024)  # 1024 = number of bytes to be recieves
        if not data:  # If data is false, or an empty string/list, etc.
            break
        print("Recieved:", data.decode('utf-8')) # Printing recieved data


# ========== CLIENT ==========

def client():
    s = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Localhost
    PORT = 65432

    s.connect((HOST, PORT)) # Connecting to server
    print("========== CLIENT ==========")
    var = 'XXXX' # Replace with actual variable
    s.sendall(f"<TRIGGER>{var}<TRIGGER>".encode('utf-8')) # Sending trigger message
    print(f"Sent: <TRIGGER>{var}<TRIGGER>")
```

Comment: Excuse my horrible spelling, there's a reason I have Grammarly ;)

Comment: Thank you so much - I used your `s.sendall(f"<TRIGGER>{var}<TRIGGER>".encode('utf-8'))` and it showed no errors  :) So I will try to check it on the server side. Thanks again

Comment: Since I'm also a beginner with socket programming, I am curious to know if it worked @JovanaBjekic. Did it?

Comment: Hi, it shows no errors - however, I don't have the access to the server-side, so I am waiting for them to tell me whether the TCP server is receiving bytes or strings. I will get back with the result as soon as I get this info :)